# Ember route loading wrong controller

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-controllers

This is part of my router

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('report', {path: '/noticia/:report_id'}, function() {
    this.route('pictures');
  });
});
```

I have defined an `App.ReportPicturesController` but my route `App.ReportPicturesRoute` insists on loading a different controller.

If I do not specify a model hook, it load the `App.ReportController`, and if I load the model I need (that is called `comment`) in loads the `App.CommentController`.

I've tried to set `controllerName` to `reportPictures` but it didn't work.

What I have to do to make the route load `ReportPicturesController`? Why is not loaded the expected controller?

**EDIT**: If it makes any difference, I'm using `ember` 1.8.1, `ember-data` 1.0.0-beta.12, and this is what the route looks like,

```
App.ReportPicturesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var report = this.modelFor('report');
    return this.store.createRecord('comment', {
      inReplyToStatus: report
    });
  }
});
```

**EDIT2**: The full source code is at https://github.com/camolin3/tweetsaster

Comment: Right now I workaround this by loading `this.controllerFor('reportPictures')` on `setupController` and `renderTemplate`, but I'd like to know why it is not loading my expected controller.

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected when I try.. have a look:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rayoje/2/

Comment: It doen't work when you click on `Pictures` nothing happens, and when I see the console it shows `Error while processing route: report.pictures`

Comment: I think it is the browser: I use to develop on Firefox (v33 and v35) and I get the error, but when I test it on Chrome 39 it shows the alert :/

Comment: I'm not being able to reproduce what is happening, I will update jsbin to make it more like my code when I have more time. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ReportRoute model hook implementation similar to this

```
App.ReportRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return {id:params.report_id}; 
        //or with ember-data return this.store.find('report', params.report_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: The `ReportRoute` is just like the ember-data version you wrote.